# Jquery Dual list Box Plugin

Tags: jquery

I am using the Jquery Dual List Box Plugin. I have more than one Dual list box in a single page so I am try to rename all the Default names by passing my own Parameters to it by using 
$.configureBoxes(options)

Here options is var option = (); --> array of values containing names for the selectboxes , buttons and other parameters.

But this never seem to work . Dont know if am passing the parameters properly

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about this specific plugin:

But an array is usually ['name1', 'name2', 'name3'], or [name1, name2, name3] if it is expecting objects.

Try brackets instead of parenthesis.

Comment: hey thanks a lot for your answer. I used curly braces and it worked.